# Drawing the slope of linear regression in my chart

Tags: google-earth-engine

I can't converse `fit` to a list. It said the `fit.reduceColums` is not a function, and I can't even use the `addBands` to the `fit` or `collection`. I'm new to this and only want to add a slope line to the chart. I failed so many times to create the list. Link to complete code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5a78c37666a323bb90f5911551067901

An extract of functional code looks as follows:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/tsukajoon/jxborderm84");

// link to the code that computes the Landsat LST
var LandsatLST = require('users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst:modules/Landsat_LST.js')

// select region of interest, date range, and landsat satellite
// var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-8.91, 40.0, -8.3, 40.4]);
var geometry = table.geometry();
var satellite = 'L7';
var date_start = '2001-01-01';
var date_end = '2021-01-01';
var use_ndvi = true;

// get landsat collection with added variables: NDVI, FVC, TPW, EM, LST
var LandsatColl = LandsatLST.collection(satellite, date_start, date_end, geometry, use_ndvi)
// print(LandsatColl)

var time1 = ['2001','2002','2003','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009'
            ,'2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
var time = ['2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
var list = ee.List([]);
Map.centerObject(geometry,6)
var cmap1 = ['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var cmap2 = ['F2F2F2','EFC2B3','ECB176','E9BD3A','E6E600','63C600','00A600']; 

for(var index in time){
  var ymd = time[index]+'-01'+'-01'
  var image = LandsatColl.filterBounds(geometry)
                         .filterDate(ymd,ee.Date(ymd).advance(1,'year'))
                         .max()
                         .select('FVC')
                         .clip(geometry)
                         .setMulti({'system:index':ymd,'system:time_start':ee.Number.parse(time[index]),'FVCName':time[index]}
                         )
  // var image = image1.addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
  // print(image)
  list = list.add(image)
  // print(list)
}

var imgYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list);
print(imgYear);

var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return image.float().addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));}
// function createTimeBand(img) {
//   var year = img.date().difference(ee.Date('2001-01-01'), 'year');
//   return ee.Image(year).float().addBands(img);
// }
var collection = imgYear.map(createTimeBand);
var fit = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());
print(fit);
var fitinfo = fit.getInfo();
var scale = fitinfo.bands[0];
var s
print('scale',scale);
Map.addLayer(fit.select('scale'), {}, "FVCslope");

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  var Time1 = ee.Image(list.get(i))
  // print(Time1)
  // Map.addLayer(Time1, {min:0.0, max:1.0, palette:cmap2}, "FVC"+i);
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: Time1,
    folder:'JiangxiFVC',
    description: 'FVC'+i,
    scale: 500,
    region: geometry,
    crs:'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'});
  }
```

Comment: Please don't paste images of code into a question. Instead, post the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your title question pointed out your desire of drawing the slope of linear regression in a chart but, however, you also began your question by saying that **Image Collection** named **fit** cannot use 'reduceColums' method for converting 'scale' property to list. As you think that it could be the main issue, I will try to answer it.

As **fit** is a computed object in GEE, you have to explicitly indicate in your code that it is an **ee.ImageCollection** object; as in following code snippet:

```
var scale = ee.ImageCollection(fit)
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(1),['scale'])
  .get('list');

print("scale by using reduceColumns", scale);
```

However, **scale** variable is printed as empty list because 'scale' property doesn't exist in this Image Collection. You have to set it previously. To exemplify the use of 'reduceColumns' method, I'm going to employ your Image Collection named **imgYear**, whose images have 'system:index' property, as follows:

```
var example = imgYear
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(1),['system:index'])
  .get('list');

print("example", example);
```

Following result is printed in Console of GEE editor.

```
 example

List (5 elements)
0: ["2016-01-01"]
1: ["2017-01-01"]
2: ["2018-01-01"]
3: ["2019-01-01"]
4: ["2020-01-01"]
```

Following [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b6d409b9fa0afa72e22c1607feace7a) runs without any errors and prints one of your charts; as it can be observed in below image.

[image]

I hope that it helps.